# webview contexual menu on select text

Tags: android, menu, android-webview

I have been trying to customize the contextual menu for a webview, that appears when selecting a text in the webview.

Basically I want to add or remove items to the menu. And add some custom event on item click.

I have already tried few solution like below links, with no success.
All I end up getting is a Dialogue menu.

https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/menus.html#CAB

[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23737510/webview-add-menu-item-to-textselection-menu

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After much trial and error, I have come to a reasonable solution.
Just posting it here for completeness, just in case anyone faces similar issue.

The solution was creating an alternative menu that I implemented using `PopupWindow`.
And I, called this on long press event using a `GestureDetector`.

```
myWebView.setWebChromeClient(new MyWebChromeClient());
mGestureDetector = new GestureDetector(getActivity(), new CustomGestureListener());
mGestureDetector = new GestureListener(getActivity(),myWebView);
final GestureDetector gd = new GestureDetector(getActivity(), mGestureDetector);

    //====== web-view popup menu
    myWebView.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent motionEvent) {
            gd.onTouchEvent(motionEvent);

            return false;
        }
    });
```

The Gesture Listener is quite basic, code can be found [here](https://gist.github.com/naxrohan/ebf350c1c444225669fc5e42e32c0df1)

Rest of the interaction with the web-view data is done using JavaScript, using below code, more about it can be found in [google dev guide](https://developer.android.com/guide/webapps/webview)

```
WebView xview = (WebView)view;
xview.loadUrl("javascript:alert(showAndroidToast('underline'))");
```

Well this has done the job for me, result can be seen in below image, hope it helps someone.

*Or unless someone has a better solution/code.*

[image]